# How to set to Black background

Tags: colors, ls

Ver: Ubuntu 21.04

In order to change the color scheme, I have set as follows in my `.bashrc`;

```
export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;96;40m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
setterm -term linux -back black -fore white -clear
export LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:"di=1;31"
```

As a result, my Terminal and PS1 background are set to black. However, output of any of the command (ls, cat, echo, etc) is still shown with grayish background. Also, moment I run "clear" command, terminal background is switched from black to grey.

How to set the background to black for all (terminal, command output, vi, etc)?

Comment: You can changes the colors in Preferences. Why use such a complicated command that obviously can only affect the current session?

Comment: Thank you @ChanganAuto. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of the community, I am posting the solution.

1. I created a new profile in Terminal → *Preferences*.
2. In the newly created profile → *Colors*, unchecked *Use color from system them* and selected the appropriate built-in theme.

[image: Terminal Preferences Setting]